# Making namespaces with the current version of Swift

Tags: namespaces, swift

Is it possible to create namespaces with the current version of Swift (while Xcode 6 is in Beta) or should I create a `framework` and import it into my project as a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespaces are implicitly inferred from module names, so the only way to define a namespace is to create a new module.